# Why isnt $_FILE set

Tags: php, html, forms, file, file-upload

here is a snippet of my html form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="profilepictureinput">Profile Picture</label>
        <input type="file"
               id="profilepictureinput"
               name="profilepicture">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When I post the form php is saying that

```
isset($_FILE['profilepicture'])
```

returns false. Why is this?

Comment: Because it's `$_FILES`

Comment: Check this link : http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: sorry i used $_FILES and its still not working

Comment: If it's like that, it might be helpful to post some more code

Comment: For reference do a print_r() of the full $_FILES array. To check what's actually in it.

Comment: this is the output of the print_r()

Comment: Array ( [profilepicture] => Array ( [name] => 45955_461403994594_8168955_n.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\php878A.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 66932 ) )

Comment: @michael sorry I cannot provide full code since I am not allowed to post company code online

Comment: @KVohra95 Sorry but if you can't even get a simple file upload to work I doubt the rest of the code would be worthwhile copying or reusing. You seek help, you do not give us code, but you expect an answer. Maybe you are in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

Change `$_FILE` to `$_FILES`

```
isset($_FILES['profilepicture'])
```

it will return `false` if the form is not submitted. After submission it will return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

As Tom Kriek already said, the correct syntax is:

```
$_FILES['profilepicture']
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need check with $_POST, if form is submitted, before you can get information from $_FILES.
You should write this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="profilepictureinput">Profile Picture</label>
        <input type="file" id="profilepictureinput" name="profilepicture">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="new-picture">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is the change:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="new-picture">Submit</button>
```

and check with `isset($_POST['new-picture'])` 
the upload() function print out the content of $_FILES array, so you can see, what is the problem.

```
<?php
//$newImageSubmitted is TRUE if form was submitted, otherwise FALSE
$newImageSubmitted = isset( $_POST['new-image'] );

if ( $newImageSubmitted ) {
    //this code runs if form was submitted
    $output = upload();
} else {
    //this runs if form was NOT submitted
    $output = include_once "views/upload-form.php";
}
return $output;

function upload(){
    $out = "<pre>";
    $out .=print_r($_FILES, true);
    $out .= "</pre>";
    return $out;
}
```